# Recovering deleted photo's original name from an SD card

Tags: data-recovery, images, photos

I know that many tools to recover deleted photos from an [SD card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital) exist, but does one also recover the original photo ID, like `DSC000754.JPG`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last time I used [Photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step) to recover deleted photos from an SD card, it successfully restored the filenames of all my recovered photos.

The [Photorec FAQ](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_FAQ#How_to_get_the_original_filenames_.3F) says that it can sometimes recover filenames from FAT-type filesystems, and also if the filename was embedded in the file itself.

Of course, this is no guarantee of success for your individual case.

Comment: What you are talking about? Photorec does *not* recover filenames because it does not analyze the file-system, but rather searches the drive sectors directly for file-type signatures (what some programs call “deep scan”) which is why it has no way to recover the name of the file or directory (it dumps everything into a single director).

Comment: Nevertheless I have some 100 restored photos from several years ago with their original filenames from running photorec. Where the filenames came from, if not from photorec, I couldn't say.

Comment: Well it’s worth a shot; Photorec is the perennial favorite of many. Perhaps an older version *did* use the file-system and then they changed it to do a deep-scan instead.

Comment: The [Photorec FAQ](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_FAQ#How_to_get_the_original_filenames_.3F) says that it can sometimes recover filenames from FAT-type filesystems, and also if the filename was embedded in the file itself. So I suspect one of those two cases was true in my case.

Comment: Actually, it says that PhotoRec’s parent program TestDisk may be able to do that, and that’s because TestDisk analyses file-systems. [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) itself specifically warns that `When a file is deleted, the meta-information about this file (file name, date/time, size, location of the first data block/cluster, etc.) is lost`. Of course results vary depending on *how* the files were lost (if you’re *really* lucky, you can get back everything but the first letter of the filenames, but who’s ever that lucky.) `:-|`

Comment: Unbelievable, I recovered all my pictures using PhotoRec with the name as _SC000754, loosing only the first 'D' letter of the photo name. Thanks a lot Michael!

Answer (score 2):

The programs that don’t recover filenames are searching the disk at a low level for signatures and headers (tell-tale patterns of bytes) of various file-types (similar to how antivirus programs detect viruses).

What you need is an “[undelete tool](https://www.google.com/search?q=undelete)” as opposed to a general data-recovery program.

[Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) (figure 1) is a popular program and has an option to do both a “deep-scan” (search for file-types) but also a normal scan that simply checks the file-system (where the folder- and filenames are stored).

Personally, I like [Undelete360](http://www.undelete360.com/) (figure 2). It too has deep and “shallow” scan options, but last year when I had to recover ~9,000 accidentally deleted graphics files, it really impressed me with its results.

Both are free.

**Figure 1**: Recuva

[image: Screenshot of Recuva]

**Figure 2**: Undelete 360

[image: Screenshot of Undelete360]